# ¿Cómo admitir letras, números, puntos y guiones con una expresión regular?

Tags: php, regex

Necesito que en un campo de formulario sólo se puedan escribir letras, números, guiones bajos, altos y puntos, mas no signos de otro tipo, como por ejemplo `" *, >, <, = "` 
 Estoy intentando hacerlo con las siguiente expresión regular, pero falla: `"/[a-zA-Z0-9]/"`, esto debería ser correcto, ya que le indico es que solo quiero alfanumérico, sin embargo falla porque también me admite signos extraños **(Carácteres especiales)**, y no sé cómo excluirlos

Comment: ¿Colocaste PHP por qué es el lenguaje en el cual deseas hacer la expresión regular?

Comment: creo que mejor haré la expresión y toda la comprobación de datos con java script, y luego el envío de datos con php, para que sea más rápido así

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida, te recomiendo leer [ask], de paso checar el [tour]; finalmente si pudieras agregar lo que llevas hecho o avanzado hasta el momento aunque tenga errores sería genial. Saludos

Answer (score 6):

Puedes crear una [clase de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) que encuentre cualquier carácter excepto los que quieres permitir (**negación**). Defines el evento `oninput` (por ejemplo) sobre el elemento correspondiente al cargar *su* DOM. Para el caso que tienes entre manos, el código puede ser similar al siguiente:

```js
var textoInput = document.getElementById("texto");

textoInput.oninput = function(event) {
  textoInput.value = textoInput.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-ZáéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ_-]/g, "");
};
```

```html
<input id="texto" placeholder="Texto" maxlength="20">
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar con este código sencillo de javascript, lo único que hace es crear un filtro y en esta incluyes los carácteres especiales que quieras, espero haya sido de ayuda!

```js
function NumText(string){//solo letras y numeros y los cácteres especiales que se requieran
    var out = '';
    //Se añaden las letras, números y carácteres válidos
    var filtro = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890*<>=';//Caracteres validos
 
    for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++)
       if (filtro.indexOf(string.charAt(i)) != -1) 
      out += string.charAt(i);
    return out;
}
```

```css
  input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  value="" class=“input-text” onkeyup="this.value=NumText(this.value)" />
```